# How to partition a very large messaging table in mysql

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table which contains messages from users. The design will keep a single copy of the message for both sender and receiver (each person has his own read/deleted flags for the message).

```
CREATE TABLE cloob_msg.cl_inbox (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  contact int(11) NOT NULL,
  sdate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  body text NOT NULL,
  userstatus tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '0: new, 1:read, 2: deleted',
  contactstatus tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  class tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  attachtype tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  attachsrc varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX i_class (class),
  INDEX i_contact_user (contact, user),
  INDEX i_contactstatus (contactstatus),
  INDEX i_user_contact (user, contact),
  INDEX i_userstatus (userstatus)
)
```

In order to list the conversation between two person, we use the following query:

```
select * from cl_inbox
    where (user=user1 and contact=user2 and userstatus<>2)
       or (user=user2 and contact=user1 and contactstatus<>2)
    order by id limit ?,?
```

Now, how can I partition the table (we have billions of messages so it really needs to be partitioned)? What unique key and what partitioning fields should I choose?

Thanks.

Comment: How about date?

Comment: I guess that will be slow. Because queries select messages based on " user and contact" fields. Isn't it? (unless you say older messages are accessed less)

Comment: The auto_inc PK already lays out the _data_ in chronological order.  Partitioning by date adds nothing.  The secondary indexes (with `UNION`, but not with `OR`) strongly limit how much I/O to do.

Comment: `INT` (which defaults to `SIGNED`) tops out at a little over 2 billion.  Your current "billions of messages" either have, or soon will, top out the auto_inc !!  It will require some downtime, but shouldn't you `ALTER TABLE messages MODIFY id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;` ??

Comment: Yes, you are right. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why partition?  It won't inherently provide any performance.

To speed up that query, change `or` to `union`:

```
( select * from cl_inbox
    where (user=user1 and contact=user2 and userstatus<>2)
    order by id limit ?,?
) UNION ALL
( select * from cl_inbox
    where (user=user2 and contact=user1 and contactstatus<>2)
    order by id limit ?,?
)
```

Now each part can independently use `i_contact_user` or `i_user_contact`.  (Your version had to do a full table scan.)  This will run a lot faster.  BTW, *for this query* those two indexes are equally good.  Unless you need both for other queries, I suggest dropping one of them.  The indexes on `*status` (and other 'flags') are probably useless, certainly useless for this query.

The next problem:  Using `OFFSET` for pagination is problematic.  And when switching to `UNION`, it is now broken.

So, instead, "remember where you left off".  Since you are saying `order by id`, I assume the ids are in the order desired by the UI?  Remove the `OFFSET` and use `id`:

```
( select * from cl_inbox
    where (user=user1 and contact=user2 and userstatus<>2)
      AND id < $left_off
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT ?
) UNION ALL
( select * from cl_inbox
    where (user=user2 and contact=user1 and contactstatus<>2)
      AND id < $left_off
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT ?
)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT ?
```

(Yes, I am deliberately repeating the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.)  And I took the liberty of turning things around -- don't you want the *latest* messages first?

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

If you expect to have a huge table, and desire to delete "old" records, then we can talk about partitioning to facilitate old rows.  But that is the only use I see for partitioning of this table.

Comment: Partitioning is because we have a billion messages in our old structure (which was also partitioned) and growing. Thanks for the query suggestion.

Comment: The other two indexes are for cleanup of deleted emails and finding spam messages (user reported classes).

Comment: If the table is bigger than can be cached in the buffer_pool, performance is mostly focused on minimizing I/O.  What other queries are common?  Optimizing indexing/partitioning/etc needs to take all queries into account at the same time.  Optimizing for one query may mess up other queries.

Comment: Reading messages (the mentioned query) and deletion/insertion are the most important and frequently used ones. Other queries are just for periodical maintenance tasks.

Comment: For the pagination I use your method in new code, but for the old code and api I am temporarily using the limit.

Comment: @wmac - `OFFSET` is the problem, not `LIMIT`.  Just read/del/ins -- Then my reformulation will help significantly on performance, and partitioning will not help at all unless you need to purge old messages.  I discuss that use of partitioning here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint